# Problem with coordinates in simple square matching game in python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm building a simple python square matching game that firstly choose random colored squares and puts them on screen so they fill the screen up. Then player randomize positions of squares and try to match square with starting positions. If he matches it, next square starts to move and he has to match it.

My squares are a little bit too big due to starting pixel size of square (21x21) that I can't change, but this is side problem.

I wrote a code that checks if square is in the right position, but it won't work with bottom left square and i don't know why... Anytime I run the code, I can match every square and everything works except one square.

I've been programming for one month, so any criticism also about efficiency of my code will be helpful!

I have 3 files:

main.py:

```
from turtle import Screen
from squares_manager import Square
from scoreboard import Scoreboard
import time

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.tracer(0)
game_is_on = True

scoreboard = Scoreboard()
scoreboard.starting_writing()

square = Square()


def combine_starting_functions():
    square.create_start_square()
    scoreboard.when_game_starts()
    square.squares_starting_pos()


screen.listen()
screen.onkey(combine_starting_functions, "space")
screen.onkey(square.randomize_squares, "Return")
screen.onkeypress(square.move_down, "Down")
screen.onkeypress(square.move_right, "Right")
screen.onkeypress(square.move_left, "Left")
screen.onkeypress(square.move_up, "Up")

while game_is_on:
    screen.update()

screen.exitonclick()
```

square_manager.py:

```
from turtle import Turtle
import random

COLORS = ["red", "blue", "pink", "yellow", "green", 'purple', "orange", "white", "brown", "cyan", "firebrick",
          "dark magenta", "peach puff", "salmon", "dark violet", "spring green"]

STARTING_SIZE = 600


class Square(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.number_of_squares = 2
        self.level = self.number_of_squares ** 2
        self.squares = []
        self.positions = []
        self.list_squares_to_move = []
        self.distance_between = STARTING_SIZE / self.number_of_squares
        self.half_of_square = self.distance_between / 2
        for square in range(self.level):
            self.list_squares_to_move.append(square)
        self.which_square = random.choice(self.list_squares_to_move)

    def create_start_square(self):
        for square in range(self.level):
            new_square = Turtle()
            new_square.hideturtle()
            new_square.shape("square")
            # new_square.shape("/Users/Łukasz/Desktop/20x20square.gif")
            ran_color = random.choice(COLORS)
            new_square.color(ran_color)
            COLORS.remove(ran_color)
            new_square.penup()
            new_square.turtlesize((STARTING_SIZE / 20) / self.number_of_squares)
            self.squares.append(new_square)

    def squares_starting_pos(self):
        increment_next_square_x = 0
        increment_next_square_y = 0
        for square in self.squares:
            square.showturtle()
            square.goto((-self.half_of_square) + increment_next_square_x, self.half_of_square + increment_next_square_y)
            increment_next_square_x += self.distance_between
            if square.xcor() > 300:
                square.setx(-300 + self.half_of_square)
                square.right(90)
                square.forward(self.distance_between)
                increment_next_square_y -= self.distance_between
                increment_next_square_x = self.distance_between
            self.positions.append(square.position())
            print(self.positions)

    def randomize_squares(self):
        for square in self.squares:
            square.goto(random.randint(-300 + self.half_of_square, 300 - self.half_of_square), random.randint
            (-300 + self.half_of_square, 300 - self.half_of_square))
            square.setheading(90)

    # def level_up(self):
    #     self.number_of_squares += 1

    def move_up(self):
        self.squares[self.which_square].forward(1)
        self.check_square_position()

    def move_down(self):
        self.squares[self.which_square].backward(1)
        self.check_square_position()

    def move_right(self):
        self.squares[self.which_square].right(90)
        self.squares[self.which_square].forward(1)
        self.squares[self.which_square].left(90)
        self.check_square_position()

    def move_left(self):
        self.squares[self.which_square].left(90)
        self.squares[self.which_square].forward(1)
        self.squares[self.which_square].right(90)
        self.check_square_position()

    def check_square_position(self):
        print(self.squares[self.which_square].position())
        print(self.positions[self.which_square])
        if self.squares[self.which_square].position() == self.positions[self.which_square]:
            self.list_squares_to_move.remove(self.which_square)
            self.next_square_to_move()
        print(self.list_squares_to_move)

    def next_square_to_move(self):
        self.which_square = random.choice(self.list_squares_to_move)
```

scoreboard_py:

```
from turtle import Turtle


class Scoreboard(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.hideturtle()
        self.penup()

    def starting_writing(self):
        self.pencolor("white")
        self.home()
        self.pendown()
        self.write("TO SEE STARTING POSITION PRESS SPACE BAR \n AFTER THAT PRESS ENTER TO START A GAME \n "
                               "             TO MOVE PRESS ARROWS", False, "center"
                   , ("arial", 15, "bold"))
        self.penup()

    def when_game_starts(self):
        self.clear()
        self.hideturtle()
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). While it is beneficial to show your work effort, it is counter productive to dump all code.  Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set which focuses on your specific problem consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).